# Get Object property by array of index

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, object

i want create a function to get a property of an object based on an array of property name

```
const getObjectProperty = (arr: string[], object: any) {
  // this function needs to return the object property
}
```

Expected Result:

Let's say i have this Object

```
const object = {
  id: 1,
  info: {
    name: "my name",
    age: 21,
    home: {
      city: "New York",
      address: "Street Name"
    }
  },
}

getObjectProperty(["info", "name"], object) // returns "my name"
getObjectProperty(["info", "name", "city"], object) // returns "New York"
getObjectProperty(["id"], object) // returns 1
getObjectProperty(["info", "salary"], object) // returns undefined
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash#get might help for complex objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use reduce of Array

```js
const array = ["info", "name"]

const object = {
  id: 1,
  info: {
    name: "my name",
    age: 21
  }
}

const val = array.reduce((acc, item) => acc[item], object)

console.log(val)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a property of an object based on an array of property names by using a **for...of** loop to iterate over the array of property names and access the corresponding properties of the object.

```
const array = ["info", "name"];

const object = {
 id: 1,
 info: {
 name: "my name",
 age: 21
 }
};

let result = object;

for (const property of array) {
  result = result[property];
}

console.log(result); // "my name"
```

It could also be done with JavaScript's reduce method in just one line

```
const result= array.reduce((result, value) => result[value], object)
```

Note that this code assumes that the property names in the array exist within the object and follow a chain of nested properties. If any of the property names are misspelled or do not exist within the object, or if the property chain is broken, the code will throw an error.